# Has the window loaded?

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight-4.0

Is there a way to verify if the page has loaded in c#, I am firing an HTML window from code, and would like to know if the window has loaded? Is that possible?

```
HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri(uri), "_blank", "toolbar=no");
```

Answer (score 0):

How things basically work:

1. Server sends a response to the browser
2. Browser accepts it (downloads html/silverlight)
3. Browser renders the page

The server has no way to know if the page is successfully loaded or if something interrupted the process after the response is sent. If you really need to know the page is loaded, you need to find it out with a client side code js or silverlight and send information/request back to the server that the page is loaded.

Comment: is there a way I can know if this window has been closed? The reason I ask is, HtmlPage is a static class, and I cannot make an object for this class to add something like a close event callback

Comment: Server side you can't know that unless you catch onunload event with JavaScript client side (and then send back information to the serve), but this is not a reliable approach. Why you need to know when an window is closed?